# How to send data to PHP server?

Tags: php, ios, objective-c

i`m having a problem doing this code to send a data to my php server 
can someone help me.
 this is my code that gives me a headache, this is my Outlets/ textfield.

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *parentsNameTextField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *professionTextField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *addressTextField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *contactTextField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *emailAddressTextField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *osTypeTextField;
```

and this is the Action Button

```
- (IBAction)registerButtonTapped:(id)sender {


 NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"&parentNameTextField=%@&professionTextField=%@",@"parentNameTextField",@"professionTextField"];



NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData length]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];




[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://a7c8a2a.ngrok.com/usermanagement_dummy/user/register"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];

NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
if (conn)
{
    NSLog(@"Connection Success");

}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Connection could not be made");

}
```

}

i`m trying my best to continue but i don`t know how to.
any help would be gladly appreciate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
NSMutableDictionary *get = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[get setObject:@"parentNameTextField" forKey:@"parentNameTextField"]; 
[get setObject:@"parentNameTextField" forKey:@"professionTextField"]; 


if([NSJSONSerialization isValidJSONObject:get]){


//convert object to data
NSData* jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:get options:kNilOptions error:nil];


NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://a7c8a2a.ngrok.com/usermanagement_dummy/user/register"]];


[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setHTTPBody:jsonData];


NSURLSessionConfiguration *config=[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];

NSURLSession *session=[NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:config];

NSURLSessionDataTask *task=[session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

    if(response){
        NSString *resp = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[data bytes] length:[data length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"Echo %@",resp);


    }

    else{
        NSLog(@"Timeout");

    }



}];
[task resume];


}
```

Make a dictionary of key value pair.Then create q `request` and `NSURLSessionDataTask` to `POST` your parameters.In the completion handler code u can get `response` also u can add `error` handling in `dataTaskWithRequest` completion handler
Try the below code.This will work for you

Comment: Thank you ! i will try this now ! :)

Comment: i have an error in  "  NSData* jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:newDatasetInfo options:kNilOptions error:nil]; "

Comment: u have replace your dict der ,i forgot to replace.Check now.For negative marker beware.This is working code

Comment: but the on my log Log saids that APP ID is not Valid.

Comment: Ohh i see now , i really appreciate this One Muku ! thanks a lot ! , its now working ! ;)

Comment: Done Muku ! thanks a lot ! haha sorry it was my 3rd time here in stack overflow thanks a lot ! MukU! :)

Comment: Someone seems to be spamming down votes at the moment. Not sure what to do about that. I gave an upvote to your working code.

Comment: The answers have a lot more value if there is some description of the problem and solution, not just "here is some code, try this".

Comment: @zaph.This is not just text.You should know to  diff who deserves negative points.We are newbies as compared to you.This is not way.U sud have commented and said this.I would have provided description den.Sometimes some dev are so busy in der job tat dey just provide the snippet of working code.Hope u understand at i am trying to say.Cheers

Comment: @muku The point is that answers should be useful in the future. Without any explanation they aren't. It takes very little time to add a sentence of so, no more than in your comment.

Comment: hmm,anyway thanks everyone specially to you sir muku.

Answer (score -1):

You can pass data through AFNetworking to php server

```
  NSMutableDictionary *dictData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
  [dictData setValue:txtUserName.text forKey:@"user"];
  [dictData setValue:txtPassword.text forKey:@"pass"];
```

> Use this method for pass request

```
NSDictionary *parameters = @{ @"name":@"login", @"body": dictData
        };
        NSString *bodyString = [self jsonStringFromID:parameters isPretty:NO];
        NSData *tempData = [bodyString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSString *bodyRequest = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:tempData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        bodyRequest = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"json=%@", bodyRequest];
        NSData *bodyData = [bodyRequest dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:CMS_HTML_URL]];
        [request setTimeoutInterval:TIME_OUT];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [request setHTTPBody:bodyData];
        AFHTTPRequestOperation *op = [[AFNetworkingClient sharedClient] HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:request success: ^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
            if ([CommonMethods isObjectEmpty:responseObject]) {
            //display alert when responseObject nil
            }
            else {
                if ([[responseObject valueForKey:@"success"] boolValue]) {
                   //print the response 
                }
            }
        } failure: ^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            //CR 6 July 2015

           //print the error
        }];
        op.responseSerializer = [kAFNetworkingClient responseSerializer];
        [[[AFNetworkingClient sharedClient] operationQueue] addOperation:op];
        [op start];
```

> pass request parameter to string

```
- (NSString *)jsonStringFromID:(id)object isPretty:(BOOL)prettyPrint {
    NSError *error;
    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:object
                                                       options:(NSJSONWritingOptions)(prettyPrint ? NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted : 0)
                                                         error:&error];

    if (!jsonData) {
        //NSLog(@"Json Print: error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
        return @"{}";
    }
    else {
        return [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    }
```